# After fresh install of 20.04 LTS, boot issues

Tags: boot, uefi

Ubuntu 20.04 boot starts, then shuts off computer, in a second or two automatically restarts the boot. Sometimes comes up to the GRUB screen and from there boots fine. Other times it starts the cycle over. Ran sudo boot-repair, that came back with this:
[image: result of boot repair]

then tried to apply. This Toshiba Satellite L305 model S5933 does not have UEFI in the bios to make changes to. My wife's Lenovo has this ability, but not this pc. So the report comes back with this link it suggests I include with any help questions.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/73qRYJWkyK/

Hope it helps...

Comment: A very low powered machine for running this version of Ubuntu.

Comment: You have to determine real root of the problem. Maybe try debugging the boot by replacing `quiet plymouth` to `verbose INIT_VERBOSE=y noplymouth` in kernel command-line inside grub. Also check RAM using memtest86, HDD using Victoria and laptop temperatures using `sensors`. Running MBR/BIOS systems in 2022 is normal, I own >3 machines which runs normally this way.